# Factory pattern and need to downcast parameter

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, factory-pattern

While refactoring my application and trying to add some abstraction to it, I found out a problem which I cannot solve by myself.

Here is an abstraction of my real problem, hope this will be easier to imagine and understand.

There is a `Container` class with a `List<IContainerItem>`.

In my application there are two types of `IContainerItem`:

- `ContainerItemA`
- `ContainerItemB`

There is also `IContainerItemFactory` with one method:

```
IContainerItem Create();
```

Also for both types of `IContainerItem` there is `IContainerItemFactory` implementation:

- `ContainerItemAFactory`
- `ContainerItemBFactory`

Now, while building the `Container` by IoC, specific type of `IContainerItemFactory` is injected, list can be populated by specific factory and everything works.

Problem started, when I added to my application `IContainerItemPart` and its two implementations:

- `ContainerItemAPart`
- `ContainerItemBPart`

Now to create `ContainerItem(A|B)` you have to pass by the constructor `ContainerItem(A|B)Part` to it. You cannot pass `IContainerItemPart` because each implementation of `IContainerIte`m use properties from specific `IContainerItemPart` implementation (different names, different number of properties)

What to do with the factories now?
Create method in the interface now looks like:

```
IContainerItem Create(IContainerItemPart part);
```

And I have two options:

1. Add casting from `IContainerItemPart` to specific in the factory Create method and pass the implementation to the constructor
2. Pass `IContainerItemPart` to `IContainerItem` implementations and cast inside (inside the constructor)

Which solution is better in your opinion? Maybe none of them? Why?
Maybe the problem is with my architecture? How to solve it then?

**UPDATE:**

I am providing some code to clarify. Code is valid C# code, except Create() methods in factories.

```
    interface IContainerItem { }

    class ContainerItemA : IContainerItem
    {
        public ContainerItemA(ContainerItemAPart part)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(part.SpecificForA);
        }
    }

    class ContainerItemB : IContainerItem
    {
        public ContainerItemB(ContainerItemBPart part)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(part.SpecificForB);
        }
    }

    interface IContainerItemPart
    {
        int Id { get; }
    }

    class ContainerItemAPart : IContainerItemPart
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SpecificForA { get; set; }
    }

    class ContainerItemBPart : IContainerItemPart
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SpecificForB { get; set; }
    }

    interface IContainerItemFactory
    {
        IContainerItem Create(IContainerItemPart part);
    }

    class ContainerItemAFactory : IContainerItemFactory
    {
        public IContainerItem Create(IContainerItemPart part)
        {
            //dont work here, downcasting needed
            return new ContainerItemA(part);
        }
    }
    class ContainerItemBFactory : IContainerItemFactory
    {
        public IContainerItem Create(IContainerItemPart part)
        {
            //dont work here, downcasting needed
            return new ContainerItemB(part);
        }
    }

    class Container
    {
        private IList<IContainerItem> _items;
        public Container(IList<IContainerItemPart> parts, IContainerItemFactory factory)
        {
            _items = new List<IContainerItem>();
            foreach (var part in parts)
                _items.Add(factory.Create(part));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `IContainerItemPart` object have the container factory to use.

```
interface IContainerItemPart{

    IContainerItemFactory getItemFactory();

}
```

that way each ItemPart will always create the correct itemFactory implementation (And possibly pass itself as a parameter to the itemFactory's constructor).

**EDIT**
Now with Code example:

Here is an implementation of `ContainerAFactory`:

```
class ContainerItemAFactory : IContainerItemFactory
{

    private IContainerItemAPart _part;

    public ContainerItemAFactory ( IContainerItemPart part){
         _part = part;
    }

    //now we don't have to pass the part subtype around as a parameter
    public IContainerItem Create()
    {
        //look no downcasting needed
        return new ContainerItemA(part);
    }
}
```

And now the `IContainerItemPart` implementation:

```
class ContainerItemAPart : IContainerItemPart
{

       ...
       public IContainerItemFactory getItemFactory(){

               return new ContainerItemAFactory (this );
       }
}
```

So in your code, you don't need to know if it's an A or B Item:

```
ContainerItem item = myItemPartFactory.getItemFactory().create();
```

Comment: Sorry but I really don't get it how this would resolve my problem? Could you give me more explanation? Maybe code that I provided could be good base for it?

Comment: now I see it and it could work for me. However I would rather have ItemPart to don't know anything about Item. In my real problem, ItemPart is from lower layer then Item.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with

```
interface IContainerItemPart{

    IContainerItemFactory getItemFactory();

}
```

is that an item might have a constructor with arguments.

Some points I would like to know.

- Do Items have parameter arguments.
- Could you post some code
- You are right to not cast
- Do you use generics (I think this is a key player here as I will explain when you respond).
- Are you having a good day?

Looking forward to the response.

Yours,

Abdulmajid Alnouri

Comment: I provided sample code. And thank you, I am having a very good day ;)